# angularjs: want to lock the object value, so when ng-change could not reset the object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

Problem: the method called in ng-change directive has a listener that watches the input(amount) and updates the `vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost` object with input change:

```
//controller
    function getAgriAmount(year,amount) {
              if (typeof amount !== "number" ) {
                amount = parseInt(amount ||0);
              };
              vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] =  amount;
            }
//view
    <md-input-container flex>
        <label translate>PROJECT.WIZARD.BUDGET.AMOUNT</label>
        <input name="localCostAmount_{{year}}_{{$index}}"
               ng-model="localCostContributor.amount"
               ng-click="vm.showExplanation('LOCAL_COST_AMOUNT')"
               ng-change="vm.getAgriAmount(year,localCostContributor.amount)"
               ain-numbers-only
               type="text"
               required>
    </md-input-container>

//controller add the amount and containing in object
    function addLocalCostContributor(localCost, year) {
                localCost.contributors.push({});
                vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < localCost.contributors.length; i++) {
                    if (angular.isDefined(localCost.contributors[i].contributor)
                    && localCost.contributors[i].contributor.name === 'Agriterra') {
                        var amount = parseInt(localCost.contributors[i].amount);
                        vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] = parseInt(vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] || 0) + amount;
                    }
                }
            }
```

the amount is added successfully, when I click add button, but if I want to add another amount for year ng- change resets it to the current amount typed, what I want is ng-change adds the new amount to the old amount that was added. I can provide more logs and info If things are not clear. Thanks!

Comment: Have you set your function on the scope? `$scope.getAgriAmount = getAgriAmount;`

Comment: yes I have  @itsphilz